# R Language: Matrix or numeric DataFrame as a scatterplot with X as the column indices, and corresponding row elements plotted against X

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, plot, scatter-plot

Let's say I have an 8 x 12 matrix:

```
> MyMatrix <- matrix(sample.int(5, 8*12, replace = TRUE), nrow = 8, ncol = 12)
> head(MyMatrix, n = 3)

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]  
[1,]    3    5    3    2    4    4    4    3    5     1     2     3 
[2,]    5    3    5    2    2    5    2    1    4     4     3     5 
[3,]    2    4    3    3    2    2    5    5    2     3     5     3
```

I want to create a scatter plot from the elements stored within `MyMatrix`. Specifically, I wish to have the column indices (1–12) represent the values of the abscissa. I want to plot the corresponding row elements for each value of *x*. In other words (considering the R output above):

- for *x* = 1, points are plotted at *y* = 3, 5, 2, ...,
- for *x* = 2, points are plotted at *y* = 5, 3, 4, ...,
- for *x* = 3, points are plotted at *y* = 3, 4, 3, ...,

and so forth.

I would similarly like to be able to achieve the same thing with a data frame rather than a matrix. Each column vector is plotted against a unique x-value. In this case, I don't say that the column indices should represent the x-values because I am imagining the possibility that one might only want to extract a subset of columns from the DF, because either the DF is not comprised entirely of numeric data types or it is simply the case that the other columns are not relevant. In this case, you could have discrete categories (e.g., number of apples owned by each "row", number of oranges owned by each "row") along the x-axis, but not necessarily so*. They could, for instance, represent time points (T1, T2, T3, etc.). The left–to–right order of each column taken from the DF should be preserved for the purposes of the plot. (That said, it isn't terribly difficult to swap or move columns around.)

*Without getting bogged down with the fact that, ultimately, the representation (numeric or otherwise) is not analog and would ultimately still be discrete in the most technical sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `matplot` for plotting the matrix - see first example.
You can also define which column not to draw - see second example, in which the third column was eliminated for plotting.

The more modern way of plotting would be the `ggplot` way where you can define your base plot and then add line by line as shown in the third example.

This all should be understood as a teaser. I would recommend to look into some literature like [R Graphics Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) for further reading.

```r
MyMatrix <- matrix(sample.int(5, 8*12, replace = TRUE), nrow = 8, ncol = 12)
matplot(MyMatrix, type = 'l')
```

[image]

```r
# if you want to leave the third column out
matplot(MyMatrix[,-3], type = 'l')

# with ggplot
library(ggplot2)
```

[image]

```r
df <- data.frame(MyMatrix)
ggplot(df, aes(x=1:8))+
  geom_line(aes(y = X1))+
  geom_line(aes(y = X2), color='red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = X3), color='green')
```

[image]

Comment: @Speleo4Life If the answer helped, you may accept it.

Comment: Unlike Cross Validated. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: First thing I did! Reputation is not high enough for it to be registered yet, unfortunately. Also, when I '@UserName', it doesn't seem to get registered in my comment: Is there special syntax for this that I am missing?

Comment: @Speleo4Life Don't worry. Yeah, it is probably the missing reputation. I have overseen this - sorry. It would just be to click the triangle. I am happy I could help. Take care.